# Undefined control sequence while writing equation

Tags: equations

I am writing an equation in LYX and I get the error "Undefined control sequence"
With the message

> "The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message
>   was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I'
>   and the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
>   and I'll forget about whatever was undefined."

```
\batchmode
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{C://Desktop}}
\makeatother
\documentclass[english]{book}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
c=\alpha+\beta[\frac{1}{\varOmega}\int_{\varOmega}\frac{|\nabla\rho(r)|}  {\rho(r)}dr]^{1/2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

How to correct that?

Comment: Could you please provide a M(N)WE?

Comment: Or at the very least, we need to know which command is undefined. I.e. what is at the end of the top line.

Comment: Often "undefined command" and such are due to errors elsewhere in equation environments (unclosed `{`, stray empty lines, missing/extra `&` or `\\\`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or simply add `amsmath` package in preamble of your document:

[image]

```
\documentclass[english]{book}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}%<-- added or {mathtools}

    \begin{document}
\begin{equation}
c=\alpha+\beta[\frac{1}{\varOmega}\int_{\varOmega}\frac{|\nabla\rho(r)|}  {\rho(r)}dr]^{1/2}
\end{equation}
    \end{document}
```

For my taste the nicer look of equation is obtained by

```
\begin{equation}
c=\alpha+\beta\left[\frac{1}{\varOmega}\int_{\varOmega}\frac{|\nabla\rho(r)|}  {\rho(r)}\mathrm{d}r\right]^{1/2}
\end{equation}
```

i.e., similarly as suggested @egred in his answer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The standard setup of LaTeX doesn't define `\varOmega`. Some font packages do.

If your aim is to get a slanted Omega, add

```
\providecommand{\varOmega}{\mathnormal{\Omega}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[english]{book}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{babel}

\providecommand{\varOmega}{\mathnormal{\Omega}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
c=\alpha+\beta[\frac{1}{\varOmega}\int_{\varOmega}\frac{|\nabla\rho(r)|}  {\rho(r)}dr]^{1/2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course the formula should be typed as

```
\begin{equation}
c=\alpha+\beta\biggl[\frac{1}{\varOmega}\int_{\varOmega}\frac{|\nabla\rho(r)|}  {\rho(r)}dr\biggr]^{1/2}
\end{equation}
```

that would produce

[image]